# DataGridView DataBindingComplete doesn't fire until after doing something in the form

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

In this form, there is a tab control.  A new tab page is added for each table in the Data Set.  Then to each tab page a Data Grid View is added for displaying the contents of the corresponding table.

This is the form's load event...You can see where I set the Data Source for the data grid view being added:

```
Public Sub dlgCreateTables_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    bindingComplete = False

    For i = 0 To binData.BinnedTables.Tables.Count - 1
        Dim tabPage As TabPage = New TabPage
        tabPage.Text = binData.BinnedTables.Tables(i).TableName
        tabTables.TabPages.Add(tabPage)

        dgvData = New DataGridView
        With dgvData
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            .DataSource = binData.BinnedTables.Tables(i)
            .Columns.Add("Total", "Total")
            .Columns("Total").ReadOnly = True
        End With

        tabPage.Controls.Add(dgvData)

        'These following lines have to go after dgvData is added to tabPage because otherwise they don't work
        dgvData.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight()

        For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvData.Columns
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        Next

        'call handler for summing the columns for each row to make Total column once binding is complete
        AddHandler dgvData.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf dgvData_Created

        'And this to show row headers in the row selectors (but not the triangle when row is selected)
        AddHandler dgvData.RowPostPaint, AddressOf MyDGV_RowPostPaint

        AddHandler dgvData.KeyDown, AddressOf dgvData_KeyDown
        AddHandler dgvData.CellValueChanged, AddressOf dgvData_CellEdit

    Next   'DataTable In binData.BinnedTables.Tables

End Sub
```

For whatever reason, the DataBindingComplete event does not fire until after the form is fully loaded and I do something like click a button or change a value in the grid.
I have a different solution in which I do the same thing and it works in there.  I can't for the life of me find anything different, or figure out why dgvData_Created isn't hit until something else happens.

Note that the contents of the tables in the Data Set to which the grids are bound are created via a separate module.  Currently I'm just filling everything with a "2" to get this issue working.

---

UPDATE:
Per Saragis's suggestion, I moved the line to add the Handler for the DataBindingComplete event up to just after instantiating the DataGridView (before "With dgvData").  Now it works in that dgvData_Created does fire when adding dgvData to the tab page, and my table is there and looks great.

However, If there is > 1 table in my data set, the DataBindingComplete event only seems to fire for the first table. After the 1st grid is done, it goes back to adding the 2nd grid but skips DataBindingComplete, and goes to RowPostPaint after the form Load is complete.

As a result, the first grid's row headers are not painted until after I force a repaint (such as by going to a different tab then coming back). And any grids after that do not have the column header row sized right (though they do show the row headers).

How can I at least force a repaint programmatically for that first grid (since that is the one I open the form to)??  I tried `.Refresh()`, but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is related to you first setting the datasource (`.DataSource = binData.BinnedTables.Tables(i)`) and then subscribing to the `DataBindingComplete` event. If you'd subscribe before setting the datasource the event will most likely fire right away. As far as I understand, that is what you are asking right?

Comment: @Saragis - Interesting - Thanks!  So I moved the line to add the handler for DataBindingComplete to before the "With dgvData".  That works now, so dgvData_Created fires right after adding dgvData to the tab page.  But for some reason only the Total column is there.  All the rows are there, but not the columns from the bound tables.  Any ideas why?